# Title of a time travel movie involving a boy in alien armor and a girl?

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, robots

So years ago I saw this move with time travel but I didn't watch it from the very beginning.

I really would appreciate finding out the title of this movie.

Some random facts from this movie (I'm not sure how well I've remembered):

- Mostly involves a boy and a girl going to future and back, and falling in love with each over along the way
- There is a scene in which a girl is being kidnapped by guy in strange looking armor. At first glance he don't even looks like a guy in an armor, but more of humanoid robot. This armor is really strange looking (don't think medieval armor; think "Aliens" armor, like aliens from "Aliens" movie). During a kidnap boy is trying to rescue girl. The chase ends up in some kind of junk yard where girl with armor guy are zapped to future. During this chase scene they (probably just the boy, I can not remember) are almost hit by a car. We later find out that:

  1. The guy in armor was actually our protagonist boy.
  2. Car was also driven by boy, with a girl as a passenger
- In the future, where girl (and at some time also boy) are being kept imprisoned underground, there are two robots. And the end of the movie we find out that they are caretakers for the Earth, which became a reserve (most of the time we rather seeing just one big robot, the other one, smaller is barely seen)
- Girl (and boy) are being imprisoned by two beings also in strange armors. These beings in armor are called "terrorists" by robots, because they still use natural resources from one time period to another. The robots listen and helps those beings in armor because they have to obey "Whoever came first trough time portal".
- After boy and a girl escape they find out when exactly terrorists came by time portal to robots. Then they go back in time even earlier to robots (to be first ones who visits them) and order robots to not listens to terrorists. They also leave drawings of the armor of the terrorists.
- Letter boy and girl go to exact moments that the terrorists are about to show up. We find out that the robots misunderstood instructions and they actually made those armors based on the drawings left by girl and boy. We then find out that it was boy and girl who where actually pretending to be terrorists and kidnapped themselves from the past to preserve the timeline
- Boy and girl at the end of the movie tell they story to a friend. He is so inspired that he became politician, someone important, and it is he who actually makes a law, which became the protocol by which robots were using the "who ever came first" rule.

Hope that's enough, because it really bothers me that I don't know the title of this movie.

UPDATE:
Some more things I remembered:

1. Main protagonists are in their late 20-something
2. The movie does not necessarily show events in chronological order. Instead, the story is shown in parts called "chapters". For example one chapter is called "Alternative timelines", or "Time paths" (or something similar), and shows a timeline which is a little different to which the viewer saw in previous chapters.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/56401/90s-or-early-2000s-scifi-miniseries-where-a-boy-and-old-man-chase-a-black-gu (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 4):

This sounds a little bit like the last movie in the [Josh Kirby - Time Warrior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josh_Kirby..._Time_Warrior!) movie series.

It has a boy and a girl travelling through past and future and they also end up falling in love. On top of that, there is an antagonist wearing a suit of robotic armor who, I think, kidnaps the girl at some point.

Comment: Can you elaborate at all on how this might match?

Comment: A made a quick edit

Answer (score 3):

I have found this movie. It is USA movie "Backtime" from 1998. Here is link to IMDb about this movie: https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0189383/

> Ex-lovers Jase and Kayla find themselves caught in a time loop when they're whisked to "The Time Chamber" by an eternal robot named Sarge (Baker) and his time refugee sidekick Zymo. Now they must restore the continuity of time, stop the time terrorists, save the world and fall in love all over again.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  Please [edit] your question to include details of the movie that match the points in the question.  Images, like the armour suit, would also be good to add.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like [**Star Kid**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120478/).

I only recall seeing a bit of it on a drive-by channel changing, so I'm not certain, but it fits pretty well.

Partial summary from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Kid):

> Spencer Griffith (Joseph Mazzello) is a shy seventh grader and 12-year-old boy. He has a crush on a school girl named Michelle (Lauren Eckstrom). Spencer's life changes when a mysterious meteorite crashes into a nearby junkyard. Investigating the site, he finds that the "meteorite" is actually a small rocket carrying a "Cyborsuit.", a prototype exoskeletal-suit with AI (short for Artificial Intelligence) from another galaxy. Spencer then decides to try the suit on and melds with the suit AI, who Spencer calls "Cy".

....

> After getting bashed multiple times by the Broodwarrior's mace and severely damaging the suit, Cy is forced to eject Spencer out before going completely offline. Spencer covers the suit with scrap metal to hide it from the Broodwarrior, takes a piece of the suit and continues to fight the Broodwarrior, who was later trying to chase down Turbo. Spencer confronts the Broodwarrior before getting chased himself and is suddenly cornered in a junked RV.

Comment: Unfotunetly no.
Film was in color.
Also "boy" and "girl" must have been missleding.
Main characters have about 20-25 years.

Answer (score -4):

I think you're thinking about [*The Time Machine*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0268695/).