# 90s (or early 2000s) scifi (mini)series where a boy and old man chase a black guy in metal suit

Tags: story-identification

I'm looking for a 90s (or early 2000s) scifi (mini)series where a boy and old man chase a black guy in metal suit. I think they were going through different dimensions. I remember part of it, but I don't think I ever saw how it ended. I remember my friend telling me there was a twist at the end. I think they were trying to find something and he was always ahead of them..

Comment: Metal suit as in shiny or just metallic as in (black/grey) body armour?

Comment: I think it was either blu-ish or red, like Tychus on starcraft 2, the memory is a bit fuzzy though
http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2307/2457256111_ff91d622a8_m.jpg

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your question was actually asked and answered already on [another StackExchange site](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/16202) (Movies and TV, currently in beta). The answer?...

[Josh Kirby... Time Warrior!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josh_Kirby..._Time_Warrior!)

The images from [rumandwrite's answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/17003) to the question should look familiar:

[image: black guy in suit]

[image: boy and old man]

The twist?...

> The guy in the suit was actually the good guy, and the white-haired scientist was evil!

Comment: Geez, thanks a lot. This is exactly it! Been looking for that for years... Again, a BIG thanks!