# Obscure 90s kids (non animated) movie/film series about two kids on a spaceship who hatch and raise alien babies

Tags: story-identification, aliens, spaceship

When I was young (in the 90's or so), I had a random VHS tape of a movie that really confused me. It could have been a mini-series because it seemed like it had some references to other things in flash back that had to do with the weird story. I don't think it was a Disney movie or anything.

The strange story:

- Two young adult/teenage kids were on a spaceship, a guy and and girl.
- They had to take care of large alien eggs for some reason
- The eggs hatched at some point
- The guy and girl have to teach the adorable alien babies the alphabet or something with large foam cut outs of letters (I didn't understand that point at all)
- Somehow they have to evacuate the ship and use the letters to somehow move the alien babies (still sitting in their egg shells)
- In another plot, a black guy gets stuck in some sort of inter-dimensional junkyard and has to repair some sort of thing like a suit or ship. Then some off-screen thing comes and hurts him more.
- In a weird flashback sequence, the guy from the ship has to run through a strange forest to get somewhere because some old lady told him to
- The black guy chases him and then gets trapped in the inter-dimensional junk yard

And that's basically all I remember.

Comment: Do you remember if it was originally in English, or could if have been dubbed?

Comment: It could have been dubbed, but I think I remember it being English

Comment: This feels very, vaguely familiar.  Can you recall what the aliens looked like? How big/small were they?  What country were you in where you found this video?

Comment: The aliens were big about as tall as the people, with big, cute eyes. I was in an asian country, I don't remember how I got the VHS tape

Comment: possible duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/56401/90s-or-early-2000s-scifi-miniseries-where-a-boy-and-old-man-chase-a-black-gu

Comment: Yeah. All depends on whether Matt is the same person as the two users who posted accepts as answers...

Answer (score 5):

Could this be part of the [*Josh Kirby… Time Warrior!*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josh_Kirby..._Time_Warrior!) series?

[image]

I've been going crazy trying to find it and it might match your story.

Comment: What about this series do you think matches the description?