# TV show / movie where a group of kids get pulled from 1 universe/planet to another; they end up in a massive playroom and are toys for a giant's child

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv

I have been trying to remember a series of videos (TV show, series of movies, or direct-to-video) I saw as a kid, possibly released in the 80s/90s/'00s. All I get is random memories of a couple of scenes here or there. I know I used to rent them as videos from Blockbuster and don't remember them ever actually airing which is why I'm not sure about the timing of the show. There is a group of kids that get pulled from either one universe to another or one planet to another. One of the scenes I remember is they end up in a massive playroom and are toys for a giant's child.

Comment: Do you remember if the setting was fantasy or science fiction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Might you be thinking of the second episode of *Josh Kirby: Time Warrior!*, "[The Human Pets](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0113485/)"?

From [this user review](https://www.imdb.com/review/rw3804478/?ref_=tt_urv):

> THE HUMAN PETS is the second in the six-film JOSH KIRBY series, following on directly from series debut PLANET OF THE DINO-KNIGHTS. That story ended on a cliffhanger of sorts, and this one carries straight on. It begins back in the medieval world and has a cool battle between cheesily-animated dinosaurs which is worth a watch alone for any B-movie lovers among us. There's a rescue attempt copied from ROBIN HOOD: PRINCE OF THIEVES and lots of low-rent hijinks and overacting.
>
> Around the halfway mark, the writer gets bored of this scenario and, perhaps sensing his target audience's brief attention spans, shifts the action to an alien world where a giant and extremely creepy-looking baby wreaks havoc with our miniature-sized heroes. Yep, it's another LAND OF THE GIANTS-type adventure, fairly amusing and funny in places, and completely cheesy, of course.

[image: DVD cover for "The Human Pets"]

[image: Alien child reaching for the protagonists]

[image: A view of the child's room, with protagonists on the table to the left]

### Preview

Comment: If so, it would be a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/56401/90s-or-early-2000s-scifi-miniseries-where-a-boy-and-old-man-chase-a-black-gu

Comment: This is it!!!!! If I could up vote you more than once I would. This has been legitimately driving me crazy on and off for years. None of my family remember it. They didn't remember spellbinder either till I was able to find it though.

Comment: @SethPeritz: You can accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons. I'm going to close this one as a duplicate, but you'll still get points for upvotes.

Answer (score 6):

I wonder if these might be the BBC TV adaptations of the Narnia novels by C.S. Lewis, *[The Chronicles of Narnia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Chronicles_of_Narnia_(TV_series))*. They were released from 1988 to 1990, and so fit with date range of the question.

Each serial covered a book of the Narnia series, from *The Lion, The Witch, and the Wardrobe* to *The Silver Chair*, and dealt with a group of children being pulled from our world to a magical land. In particular, in [The Silver Chair](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0098912/?ref_=tt_ov_inf) the children, Eustace and Jill, are held captive by some giants who want to eat them. At first the giants appear friendly and put the children in a giant playroom, holding giant-size toys. Admittedly the children do not end up as toys for a giant child though, which differs from the question.

Comment: Thanks I did watch that series as well, love it, and do have it on DVD. But that's not it. Thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

You might be thinking of [*Explorers* (1985)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0089114/) ([Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explorers_(film)).

A boy repeatedly dreams about a circuit board. He tells his friends about it, and they manage to build the circuit which turns out to generate a force field. Another dream gives them another circuit which produces oxygen. They manage to build spaceship out of junkyard parts, including a [tilt-a-whirl car](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tilt-A-Whirl). They go for a flight and find themselves drawn to an alien spaceship.

> On the ship they meet a pair of aliens. The aliens have been studying earth culture, mostly television, and don't fully understand it. The humans and the aliens manage to communicate with each other. It turns out the aliens sent the dreams, hoping to get the humans come for a visit.

> Then another even larger spaceship arrives, bearing larger versions of the aliens. It becomes clear the aliens on the first ship were essentially children who took the first ship out for a joyride, and now their parents have shown up.

Comment: It's been a while since i watched the movie, but were the aliens giants?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots The first set of aliens were somewhat larger than human-sized. The parents were much larger.

Comment: This is not it but I wish I had seen this as a kid.